# The etymology of the word "Stimmung"

Tags: etymology, heidegger

According to Heidegger there is an existential bond between Dasein and Stimmung. I wonder if there exist an etymological link between the word Stimmung and the word Sein.

Comment: I heavily doubt so.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Are you able to link & quote a source where Heidegger says so (about the bond)?

Comment: Thanks,

Paragraph 29 in Being and Time

§ 29. Da-sein as Attunement [Befindlichkeit]
What we indicate ontologically with the term attunement is ontically what is most familiar and an everyday kind of thing: mood [Stimmung], being in a mood.
Prior to all psychology of moods, a field which, moreover, still lies fallow,
we must see this phenomenon as a fundamental existential and outline its
structure.

Comment: I am as far from a philosopher as a person can be. But looking for "attunement" lead me to "Bestimmtsein", which rather could be understood as a definition, a concretion, what makes up an entity. If we could have the original phrase it would make things easier, i think. But "Stimmung" as a more ephemeral state of mind or view may simply not be the right term here ...

Comment: @a_donda Look at https://taradajko.org/get/books/sein_und_zeit.pdf.Quote: § 29. Das Da-sein als Befindlichkeit.  Was wir ontologisch mit  dem  Titel  Befindlichkeit  anzeigen,  ist  ontiscb das  Bekannteste  und  Alltäglichste:  die  Stimmung,  das  Gestimmtsein.  Vor  aller  Psychologie  der  Stimmungen,  die  zudem  noch  völlig  brach  liegt,  gilt  es,  dieses  Phänomen  als  fundamentales Existenzial zu sehen und in seiner Struktur zu umreißen.

Comment: https://taradajko.org/get/books/sein_und_zeit.pdf

Comment: Danke. Na, von unsem heutigen Wissensstand über fast 3 Millionen Jahre Menschheitsgeschichte klingt seine Interpretation ja schon ziemlich verallgemeinernd, verschleiernd sogar und beeinflußt von seiner persönlichen Umwelt. The Being being cast into its environment, unfit to act on its own will, being shaped and formed. Be it as it may, it seems to be Heidegger's view and not necessarily common German language :-)

Comment: This theme is worked out thoroughly in his The Fundamental Concepts of Metaphysics: https://b-ok.cc/book/1202020/57ad1d

Answer (score 7):

"Stimmung" derives from "Stimme", not from "Sein".

https://www.dwds.de/wb/Stimmung

Comment: thut mir nicht leid, aber ich glaub das *stimmt* nicht.

Answer (score 1):

This should be difficult to decide, if the etymology of *Stimm-* is uncertain.

---

DWDS / Wolfgang Pfeifer at least isn't sure; Wiktionary instead agrees with Kroonen (fig. 1) linking several words for "mouth", which Pfeifer suggests merely as "möglich" (see the link to DWDS in @fdb's answer). Kroonen even links *mouth* itself, assuming a zero-grade *(st)m- would be an impossible cluster and therefore elided to *m-, thus also Latin *mentum* "chin".

Kroonen further aduces that a relation to PIE *steH- were "impossible in view of the Germanic evidence for e-vocalism" (viz *stehen, stand*).

One PIE root glossed "to cut" is mentioned in wiktionary and DWDS, but not by Kroonen.

[image: Fig. 1 (Guus Kroonen, Etymologic Dictionary of Proto-Germanic, 2013, Brill: Leiden - Boston)]

---

For sake of the argument, let's assume your hypothesis were correct, though.

There is a good comparison in *system*

> From Middle French sisteme, systeme (modern French système (“system”)), or directly from its etymon Late Latin systēma (“**harmony; musical scale;** set of celestial objects; set of troops; system”), from Ancient Greek σύστημα (sústēma, “musical scale; organized body; whole made of several parts or members”), from σῠν- (sun-, prefix meaning ‘with, together’) + ἵστημι (hístēmi, “to stand”) (from Proto-Indo-European *steh₂- (“to stand (up)”)) + -μᾰ (-ma, suffix forming neuter nouns denoting the result of, a particular instance of, or the object of an action).
>
> [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/system *bold emphasis mine*]

this would be *sem- + *steH-, but only through Greek. *steH- is one of the more significant roots. It should be really hard to say whether it had anything to do with *sein*, *ist*, PIE *Hesti-, *Hes-, and similar.

---

DWDS again treats v. *stimmen* shortly:

> **stimmen** Vb. ‘zusammenpassen, richtig sein, übereinstimmen, seine Stimme für jmdn., etw. abgeben’, mhd. *stimmen* ‘eine Stimme hören lassen, rufen, mit einer Stimme versehen, erfüllen, anstimmen, nennen, festsetzen, abschätzen’ und ahd. *gistimnen* ‘zusammen-, anstimmen’ (8. Jh.); in der Musik ‘die Höhe der einzelnen Töne kontrollieren’ (16. Jh.), ‘jmdn. in eine bestimmte Gemütslage versetzen’ (18. Jh.)

It's far from obvious how this should relate to "mouth" or "to cut", although it can be construed as a week verb to *Stimme* (vox), but the oldest sense being music related is notable.

Assuming conflation (or merger) of different etymons seems preferable in order to maintain your hypothesis while accepting Kroonen's. Whether it's possible, or even likely is another matter.

---

I want to add several tangents towards such a possibility, but this answer is already long enough and the shear amount of theory necessary to make it work is overwhelming for the time being.

Suffice to say that Heidegger was likely not making an argument from etymology, however a good argument towards it.

---

Addendum: 
If you are still interested, I can only recommend to investigate the roots next to "mouth" in Kroonen's dictionary very carefully. Just for example:

When searching *mouth* in Kroonen, several other terms appear beforehand that draw attention. In no particular order:

- For one, there is *Vormundschaft* ("OHG *munt* 'protection'") which have little to do with MHG *Mund* "mouth", apparently, but should reconstruct PGem *mundo, f. "hand", PIE ***mh2-nt-eh2-** "often compared to Lat. *manus* (cf. De Vaan 2008: 363-4), but in spite of the obvious semantic match, the deeper link with the root **meh2-* 'to beckon' has not been established." Nevertheless he goes on to adduce further evidence to construe the root, and for a suffix *-nt-.
- The lemma *mundo also quoted Faroese *munda* "'to be able to grasp'" which is curious because "to be able" appears elsewhere, too, as there are

  - a) "OFri. *mota* pret.-pres. 'to be allowed, to be able, to have to'" under *motan "'w[eak] v[erb] 'to approach, concede to(?)', with MHG *müssen*, En *must*, from PIE *mod-;
  - b) PGem *mugan pret.-pres. 'to be able' with *mögen*, *may*, etc.

  I have admittedly no idea what a preterite-presence is, if not a paradox. The Frisian etymon, where *g* frequently elided, may be a conflation with *muga, moga* (< *mugan), imho by the way.

  (a) *motan is right next to, and references, *motjan "to meet". I recall "to meet a decision", which seems notable in view of *[ab]stimmen*

Perhaps consider other tangents as well: *vox, dico, dedicate, devote, vote, atmosphere, tenor, einstellen (einsetzen, zusammenstellen, consider), decide, fällen, Gefühl, convict, convince*, etc., etc.; at your own risk, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your laborious and extensive answer. I do know that Heidegger does not make an argument from etymology. I was just curious to know about a possible etymological link.